# PHP Regex ignore string between specific characters

Tags: php, regex

I use regex to add markup to my website and I would like for **string** to only make the string **bold** if the string and asterisks are not between four brackets like so: [[**string**]] in this case the four asterisks and the string should stay the same and not dissapear or turn bold.
I hope this is possible with regex.

For detecting when a string is between four asterisks I use this regex /**(.+?)**/
And for detecting when a string is between fourd brackets I use /[[(.+?)]]/s

Comment: Please supply a sample input string that represents the simpler and more complex types of substrings that you expect to encounter.   Then show your exact desired output for that string.

Comment: So what exactly is your question? What error do you encounter? And please show us the code you already tried. [This guide can help you with that](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

You might use

```
(?<!\[\[|\*)\*\*(?!\*)(.+?)(?<!\*)\*\*(?!\*|]])
```

The pattern matches

- `(?<!\[\[|\*)` Negative lookbehind, assert `[[` or `*` to the left
- `\*\*(?!\*)` Match `**` and negative lokoahead to assert not `*` to the right
- `(.+?)` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ chars as least as possible
- `(?<!\*)\*\*` Negative lookbehind, assert not `*` to the left and match `**`
- `(?!\*|]])` Negative lookahead, assert not `*` or `]]` to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hR4ayQ/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/2vUjg)

Another option might be matching all that you don't want and then making use of SKIP FAIL

```
(?:\[\[.*?]]|\*{3,}.*?\*+|\*+.*?\*{3,})(*SKIP)(*F)|\*\*(.+?)\*\*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/D5FQYI/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/7cRUQ)

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing how much variability there is in your input string, I'd say you can simply match and discard the substrings that are double square brace and double asterisk wrapped and then match&capture the non brace wrapped substrings that are only asterisk wrapped.

There are fringe cases (like nested square braced substrings) where this will fail, but I don't know if they are reasonably likely to occur.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/jiADk))

```
$text = <<<TEXT
Text **bold** [[**not
bold**]]
TEXT;

echo preg_replace(
         '~\[{2}\*{2}.*?\*{2}]{2}(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\*{2}(.*?)\*{2}~s',
         '<b>$1</b>',
         $text
     );
```

Output:

```
Text <b>bold</b> [[**not
bold**]]
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need id to match only `**string**` not preceded by `[` and should so :

- `(?<!\[)` Negative lookbehinds to make sure tring not preceded by `[`
- `(?:[\*]{2})` string must be precded by two `**`
- `([^\[\]\*]+)` string match
- `(?:[\*]{2})` string must end with two `**`

`(?<!\[)(?:[\*]{2})([^\[\]\*]+)(?:[\*]{2})`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/s0J5kO/1)

PHP code :

```
<?php
$str="[[**string**]]**string**[[**string**]]**string****string****string** [[**string**]]**string**[[**string**]]**string****string****string**[[**string**]]**string**[[**string**]]**string**[[**string**]][[**string**]]**string****string****string****string**abcd*abcdefg*abcdefgh**abcd***[**string**]]";
$pattern = '/(?<!\[)(?:[\*]{2})([^\[\]\*]+)(?:[\*]{2})/';
$replacement = '<b>$1</b>';
$str= preg_replace($pattern, $replacement,$str);
print $str;
?>
```